# Issue with Firebase Function Integration

Tags: android, node.js, firebase

I have a issue with Firebase Function Integration, when I type :E:\APPS\Main Code\Android Code\app\GameRoom>firebase login
 This is what I get:
? Allow Firebase to collect anonymous CLI usage and error reporting information? Yes
Visit this URL on any device to log in: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=563584335885-fgrh(...) Waiting for authentication…

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

on debug debug Error: spawn cmd ENOENT at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19) at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)

I try with firebase login—no-localhost, but the same thing ,dosen’t work
If I click on the link I DON`T receive the message : Woohoo!
Firebase CLI Login Successful
You are logged in to the Firebase Command-Line interface. You can immediately close this window and continue using the CLI.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows then try running a separate cmd as admin and then use **firebase login**